# Uploading txt file to folder located on server via FTP c#

Tags: c#, ftp, text-files

Iv googled this and come across quite a few tutorials which is fine but im getting a small error "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

This is my code

```
 try
            {
                // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/array1/Despatch");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");

                // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DespatchExpressData"]));
                byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                sourceStream.Close();
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
            }
```

Before calling the above method a textfile is created and saved in a folder within the solution of my project called DispatchDetails the txt file is called Data.txt im using StreamReader to get the txt file and then trying to upload it to the Folder on the FTP Account

Iv even tried hard coding the streamreader part and still get the error :(

it falls over on this line

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8caa2570-f185-4c31-91b3-940ab7c7c3a2)

Probably you have to set correct URI for `WebRequest.Create`, like

```
WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX//array1/Despatch");
```

And, of course, check, if you have permissions to write :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link and information iv followed that link made some modifications my end and still the same error, iv also checked the permissions and i have read and write so i dont see what else i could be doing wrong here..... :(

Comment: Maybe you should try to add extension for uri, ".txt"?

Comment: what do you mean extension for uri?

Comment: WebRequest.Create("ftp://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX//array1/Despatch/textfile.txt")

Comment: Hi thanks for the information i found this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17202/Simple-FTP-demo-application-using-C-Net-2-0 and re-done my code and it seems to be working fine now

Comment: @JleruOHeP +1 for showing `//` before the folder name.  This helped me to fix my problem and FYI: filename is mandatory `WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX//foldername/filename.ext`